# SDN Controller subscribing to MQTT

Tags: networking, controller, mqtt, sdn

I'm new to networking and so I hope this question makes sense.

My plan is to set up a router where I will capture probe requests, packet loss and signal strength. Once captured messages will be published about these events via MQTT. I would now like to involve an SDN controller in to this network and react depending on these messages.
My question is, is it possible for an SDN controller to subscribe to these messages?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Which SDN controller are you using? It may have an API you can use to add MQTT support

Comment: I am currently using opendaylight but I have done very little with the controller and so would have no problem changing to a different SDN controller

Comment: You may need to implement Northbound API for MQTT publisher.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I'll try and figure out how to do this